# Start a Method only when other fragment is destroyed

Tags: java, android, fragmentmanager

I want to start a method in a fragment, but not before the fragment is visible (there is another fragment with a countdown "on top")
How can I wait for the other fragment to be closed before starting the method?
Thanks a lot!

**This is the fragment where the two new fragments are initialized and put on backstack:**

```
Fragment ontimeFragmentCD = new OntimeCDFragment(reps, restMinutes, restSeconds, workMinutes,       workSeconds);
          replaceFragment(ontimeFragmentCD);
          Fragment fragment_startcd_fs = new fragment_startcd_fs();
          replaceFragment(fragment_startcd_fs);
```

**This is the code of the first fragment being closed and calling the second fragment from backstack:**

```
public void close(){
   getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

**This is the Method in the onViewCreated Method that shoud start automatically, but only after the first fragment being closed:**

```
  //Method for Training
    restwork(false, false);
```